# mysql docker container does not start on windows. erro: mysql exited with code 1. Can somone help me?

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

[this is my docker-compose code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlWoM.png)

Comment: Do not post images as question, instead copy the content as text. This will help users to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information about the error?

Just going off of what you provided, I would try using something like this:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'manage_car'
      MYSQL_USER: 'manage_car'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'manage_car'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'manage_car'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  my-db:
```

There's also a good tutorial for running mysql with Docker Compose [here](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/develop/)

Comment: the only one error i had was  mysql exited with code 1. 
I don't nkow how but now, it's works.  i just changed restart: unless-stopped with restart: always and the name of MYSQL_DATABASE